# DrawerLayout with Admob ad

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am using Navigation-Drawer in my application.So I have created single activity with navigation_drawer layout.I am using fragments to change main content area(@+id/content_frame) data whenever user chooses a menu option from navigation drawer menu.Now my problem is that I want to show admob ad on every screen.I could used fragments to initialize ad layout and inflate it into FrameLayout but I think would be not a good option.Is their any way to initialize ad using that single activty?

**navigation_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/side_navigation_background"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/side_navigation_list_divider_color"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use any layout inside of DrawerLayout. In the .xml shown below you can switch fragments in the single activity (using RelativeLayout) with admob ad in the bottom of this activity.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
                android:background="@color/background" />

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="AD_UNIT_IT"
                ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                android:gravity="bottom" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even when a fragment is included in a drawerlayout, adview can be added using relativelayout like

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```